# remove key of matched number in [String:[NSNumber]]

Tags: arrays, swift, higher-order-functions

How to remove a value from dictionary with array of values. I have response from server like below:

```
[  
   "business_proof":[  
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      -1,// business_proof contains -1, I want to remove this key like wise any other contains
      0,
      0
   ],
   "reference_proof":[  
      1,
      2,
      1
   ],
   "vehicle_proof":[  
      1,
      1,
      2
   ],
   "previous_loan_track":[  
      2,
      2,
      0,
      0,
      2,
      2
   ],
   "banking_proof":[  
      1,
      1
   ],
   "income_proof":[  
      0,
      0,
      2,
      0,
      2,
      1,
      2,
      0,
      0
   ],
   "signature_proof":[  
      2,
      2,
      1,
      2,
      2,
      2
   ],
   "employment_proof":[  
      2,
      1,
      2,
      2,
      2,
      2,
      2
   ],
   "guarantor_proof":[  
      1,
      2,
      2
   ],
   "pdc_proof":[  
      1,
      0
   ],
   "address_proof":[  
      2,
      2,
      2,
      2,
      2,
      2,
      2,
      2,
      2,
      2,
      2,
      2,
      2,
      2,
      3
   ],
   "age_proof":[  
      2,
      2,
      2,
      2,
      2,
      2,
      1,
      2
   ],
   "contact_proof":[  
      0,
      2,
      2
   ],
   "photo_id_proof":[  
      2,
      2,
      2,
      2,
      2,
      2,
      2,
      2,
      2,
      2
   ]
]
```

Second reponse

```
[  
   "signature_proof":[  
      "pan_card",
      "driving_licence",
      "accepted_documents",
      "passport",
      "cancelled_cheque",
      "bank_report"
   ],
   "guarantor_proof":[  
      "accepted_documents",
      "co_applicant",
      "guarantor"
   ],
   "previous_loan_track":[  
      "housing_loan",
      "vehicle_loan",
      "over_draft_limit",
      "accepted_documents",
      "business_loan",
      "personal_loan"
   ],
   "address_proof":[  
      "bank_statement",
      "voter_id",
      "rental_agreement",
      "eb_bill",
      "registration_document",
      "hr_letter",
      "driving_licence",
      "property_tax_receipt",
      "telephone_bill",
      "cc_statement",
      "gas_bill",
      "aadhaar_card",
      "passport",
      "ration_card",
      "accepted_documents"
   ],
   "vehicle_proof":[  
      "vehi_insurance",
      "vehi_rc",
      "accepted_documents"
   ],
   "business_proof":[  
      "business_commencement_certificate",
      "ssi_msme_certificate",
      "business_transactions",
      "mou",
      "aoa",
      "gst_no",
      "tan_no",
      "business_agreements",
      "accepted_documents",
      "shop_and_establishment_certificate",
      "incorporation_certificate"
   ],
   "banking_proof":[  
      "bank_statement",
      "accepted_documents"
   ],
   "income_proof":[  
      "form_16",
      "profit_loss_statement",
      "rental_income_proof",
      "payslip",
      "income_in_cash_proof",
      "accepted_documents",
      "brokerage_income_proof",
      "it_returns",
      "audited_balance_sheet"
   ],
   "reference_proof":[  
      "ref2",
      "accepted_documents",
      "ref1"
   ],
   "employment_proof":[  
      "employee_id_card",
      "accepted_documents",
      "payslip",
      "relieving_letter",
      "comp_app_letter",
      "hr_letter",
      "epf_no_uan_no"
   ],
   "age_proof":[  
      "employee_id_card",
      "ration_card",
      "pan_card",
      "passport",
      "voter_id",
      "school_certificate",
      "accepted_documents",
      "aadhaar_card"
   ],
   "contact_proof":[  
      "accepted_documents",
      "landline_bill",
      "mobile_bill"
   ],
   "photo_id_proof":[  
      "employee_id_card",
      "nrega_card",
      "ration_card",
      "bank_passbook",
      "pan_card",
      "passport",
      "voter_id",
      "driving_licence",
      "accepted_documents",
      "aadhaar_card"
   ],
   "pdc_proof":[  
      "cheque_book",
      "accepted_documents"
   ]
]
```

Both are array of dictionary, Both will have same key only. I know this structure is completely wrong.

**business_proof** only contains - 1, so i want to remove both places.

Here i need to remove key and values if anyone key values contains -1.

I am trying like this but it shows compiler error

```
finalValueArray.removeAll(where: { $0.contains(-1) })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` as far as I understand

```
var filteredItems = object.filter { !$0.value.contains(-1)}
```

You can get all elements which contain -1

```
var minusOneItems = object.filter { $0.value.contains(-1)}
```

and than

```
for negativeItem in minusOneItems {
    object.removeValue(forKey: negativeItem.key)
}
```

It depends what you need.

Comment: any way get to index as well

Comment: index of -1 or index of the object that contains -1

Comment: Index of the object that contains -1

Comment: you can inverse the filter and you can have the objects containing -1. And then working with keys inside. Why do you need the index of the object?

Comment: I have one more array with different values and need to remove them as well

Comment: can explain more, because if you have a dictionary you need just the keys after that.

Comment: there are two kind of dictionary same key with different values, if first dictionary removes any key and need to remove it in  another dictionary as well

Comment: I just update the answer I think this is what you need.

Comment: @karthikeyan Removing values from another dictionary based on an index isn't good. Compare the keys and delete values from another dictionary

Comment: my answer will work perfectly for you just on the line object.removeValue(forKey: negativeItem.key) object is the second dictionary. You can optimize if you just find minusOneItems and iterate with them and remove it from the two dictionaries that you have.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a combination of **`forEach`** and **`contains`** on the `dictionary` like so,

```
var dictionary = ["business_proof": [0, 0, 1, -1, 2, -1], "reference_proof": [1, 2, 1], "vehicle_proof": [-1, 0, 0, 2]]

dictionary.forEach { (key,value) in
    dictionary[key] = value.contains(-1) ? nil : value
}

print(dictionary) //["reference_proof": [1, 2, 1]]
```

Or you can simply apply **`filter`** on `dictionary` like,

```
dictionary = dictionary.filter({ !$0.value.contains(-1) })

print(dictionary) //["reference_proof": [1, 2, 1]]
```

Comment: thanks for replying me ...I want to remove that object not -1 value

Comment: Updated the answer by the way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `while` loop to remove all `key-value` pairs which contain `-1` from both dictionaries.

```
var dict1 = ["business_proof":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0],"reference_proof":[1,2,1],"vehicle_proof":[1,1,2],"previous_loan_track":[2,2,0,0,2,2],"banking_proof":[1,1],"income_proof":[0,0,2,0,2,1,2,0,0],"signature_proof":[2,2,1,2,2,2],"employment_proof":[2,1,2,2,2,2,2],"guarantor_proof":[1,2,2],"pdc_proof":[1,0],"address_proof":[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3],"age_proof":[2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2],"contact_proof":[0,2,2],"photo_id_proof":[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]]
var dict2 = ["signature_proof":["pan_card","driving_licence","accepted_documents","passport","cancelled_cheque","bank_report"],"guarantor_proof":["accepted_documents","co_applicant","guarantor"],"previous_loan_track":["housing_loan","vehicle_loan","over_draft_limit","accepted_documents","business_loan","personal_loan"],"address_proof":["bank_statement","voter_id","rental_agreement","eb_bill","registration_document","hr_letter","driving_licence","property_tax_receipt","telephone_bill","cc_statement","gas_bill","aadhaar_card","passport","ration_card","accepted_documents"],"vehicle_proof":["vehi_insurance","vehi_rc","accepted_documents"],"business_proof":["business_commencement_certificate","ssi_msme_certificate","business_transactions","mou","aoa","gst_no","tan_no","business_agreements","accepted_documents","shop_and_establishment_certificate","incorporation_certificate"],"banking_proof":["bank_statement","accepted_documents"],"income_proof":["form_16","profit_loss_statement","rental_income_proof","payslip","income_in_cash_proof","accepted_documents","brokerage_income_proof","it_returns","audited_balance_sheet"],"reference_proof":["ref2","accepted_documents","ref1"],"employment_proof":["employee_id_card","accepted_documents","payslip","relieving_letter","comp_app_letter","hr_letter","epf_no_uan_no"],"age_proof":["employee_id_card","ration_card","pan_card","passport","voter_id","school_certificate","accepted_documents","aadhaar_card"],"contact_proof":["accepted_documents","landline_bill","mobile_bill"],"photo_id_proof":["employee_id_card","nrega_card","ration_card","bank_passbook","pan_card","passport","voter_id","driving_licence","accepted_documents","aadhaar_card"],"pdc_proof":["cheque_book","accepted_documents"]]

while let invalid = dict1.first(where: { $0.value.contains(-1) }) {
    dict1.removeValue(forKey: invalid.key)
    dict2.removeValue(forKey: invalid.key)
}
print(dict1)//["reference_proof":[1,2,1],"vehicle_proof":[1,1,2],"previous_loan_track":[2,2,0,0,2,2],"banking_proof":[1,1],"income_proof":[0,0,2,0,2,1,2,0,0],"signature_proof":[2,2,1,2,2,2],"employment_proof":[2,1,2,2,2,2,2],"guarantor_proof":[1,2,2],"pdc_proof":[1,0],"address_proof":[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3],"age_proof":[2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2],"contact_proof":[0,2,2],"photo_id_proof":[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]]
print(dict2)//["signature_proof":["pan_card","driving_licence","accepted_documents","passport","cancelled_cheque","bank_report"],"guarantor_proof":["accepted_documents","co_applicant","guarantor"],"previous_loan_track":["housing_loan","vehicle_loan","over_draft_limit","accepted_documents","business_loan","personal_loan"],"address_proof":["bank_statement","voter_id","rental_agreement","eb_bill","registration_document","hr_letter","driving_licence","property_tax_receipt","telephone_bill","cc_statement","gas_bill","aadhaar_card","passport","ration_card","accepted_documents"],"vehicle_proof":["vehi_insurance","vehi_rc","accepted_documents"],"banking_proof":["bank_statement","accepted_documents"],"income_proof":["form_16","profit_loss_statement","rental_income_proof","payslip","income_in_cash_proof","accepted_documents","brokerage_income_proof","it_returns","audited_balance_sheet"],"reference_proof":["ref2","accepted_documents","ref1"],"employment_proof":["employee_id_card","accepted_documents","payslip","relieving_letter","comp_app_letter","hr_letter","epf_no_uan_no"],"age_proof":["employee_id_card","ration_card","pan_card","passport","voter_id","school_certificate","accepted_documents","aadhaar_card"],"contact_proof":["accepted_documents","landline_bill","mobile_bill"],"photo_id_proof":["employee_id_card","nrega_card","ration_card","bank_passbook","pan_card","passport","voter_id","driving_licence","accepted_documents","aadhaar_card"],"pdc_proof":["cheque_book","accepted_documents"]]
```

---

---

Create a `struct` and initialize the struct objects with both dictionary values. Then store the struct objects in an array. Now you can filter the array by its values

```
struct Proof {
    var title: String
    var arr: [Int]
    var documents: [String]
}
var proofs = [Proof]()
dict1.forEach {
    if let docs = dict2[$0.key] {
        proofs.append(Proof(title: $0.key, arr: $0.value, documents: docs))
    }
}
print(proofs)
let validProofs = proofs.filter { !$0.arr.contains(-1) }
print(validProofs)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter your dictionary to remove the entries that contains -1 in their value.

```
let filteredArrayOnDict = dataDict.filter {  value.contains{ $0 != -1 } }
```

The **filteredArrayOnDict** is the array of tuples. Now if you want to create a dictionary from it. You can do this way:

```
let filteredDictionary = filteredArrayOnDict.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.0] = $1.1}
```

Now you have the only the entries in filteredDictionary that doesn't have -1 in their value.

Answer (score 1):

Enumerate the index dictionary, look for occurrences of -1 and filter the `indices`. Then reverse the found indices and remove the items in both arrays. The code considers that both dictionaries are value types

```
var indexDict = ["business_proof":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0] ...
var valueDict = ["signature_proof":["pan_card","driving_licence","accepted_documents","passport","cancelled_cheque","bank_report"] ...


for (key, value) in indexDict {
    let foundIndices = value.indices.filter({value[$0] == -1})
    for index in foundIndices.reversed() {
        indexDict[key]!.remove(at: index)
        valueDict[key]!.remove(at: index)
    }

}
```